# Finding a table's row height

Tags: tables, pdftex

I have two tables, one of which has two rows as a header. The first table's header looks something like this:

```
\toprule
\footnotesize\textsc{Stars}\\
\tiny{Name} & \tiny{SHA} & \tiny{Dec}\\
\midrule
```

I want the second table's header rows to be the same height, but with only the second line of text:

```
\toprule
\\
\tiny{Latitude}\\
\midrule
```

Because of the difference in text sizes between the two rows, PdfLaTeX makes the second table's top row narrower so the `\midrule` doesn't line up with the first table's. The contents of the tables are different enough that I can't just create one table.

Is there a way of determining a row's height, or should I create a box for each column of a fixed height?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start the second table with

```
\toprule
\vphantom{\footnotesize\textsc{Stars}}\\
\tiny{Latitude}\\
\midrule
```

With `\vphantom` only the height (and depth) will be considered and not the width.

Comment: Alternative to use `\vphantom` you may use `\strut` after (or - if you want more line space - before) `\footnotesize` at both tables to have a defined minimum height and depth. But the result needn't be the same! So try it out.

Comment: Thanks @egreg and @Schweinebacke. Because this table is the exception, I've gone for the `\vphantom` option, but `\strut` does strike me as a neater way of doing it.